# ℘(S) = { T | T ⊆ S } shouldn't T be a proper subset of S and not an improper one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I saw this many times but I don't understand why it is an improper subset. The power set has all the elements S has and more so they are not equal making them proper subsets and not improper ones no? Or it doesn't matter that much if I put proper subset or not here?

Comment: It's just a definition. It's really convenient to include $S\in\mathscr{P}(S)$, why not? $S$ is a subset of itself, so...

Comment: The elements of $P(S)$ are defined as improper subsets because $S$ is itself a member of $P(S).$ That's all there is to that

Comment: "The power set has all the elements S has and more" -- Taken literally, this is not usually true.  It's definitely not workable as a _definition_ of the power set, which is what we'd need to contrast your question against.